# How can I use secrets during docker build?

Tags: .net, docker

I'm working with a project that requires access to a secure NuGet server, meaning it needs user creds. During development, we simply run a couple nuget commands to store those creds on the local machine. On the build server, those same commands a run before build using values that are encrypted so that they can be safely stored in the build configuration. The issue now is that when building a new docker image from that project, that docker build image will need those same values in order to build the project within the container. How can I get those values into the docker build image in a secure fashion?

I looked into docker secrets, but it would seem that it only works in deployments (e.g. docker-compose) which doesn't solve the problem which is that the project cannot build within the docker build image if it cannot access the private nuget server in order to restore the packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker secrets are only available within Swarm Mode services. Docker stores them within the swarm manager's database, which can't be used external to swarm mode. A docker build runs outside of swarm mode, and there's no option to run a build inside of swarm mode. You also don't get volume mounts inside of the build, that happens later.

At best, you can run an initial container in swarm mode, with a constraint to run on the build node. That container could have the secrets mounted in addition to a bind mount volume to a directory on the host. And from that container, you could copy a secret out of the secure secret to the host directory (docker will keep your secrets secure, but there's nothing stopping you from doing something insecure with that secret yourself). Once you've copied the secret out, you can run your build with the secret as a build arg.

Unfortunately, I wouldn't consider any of this secure since you're now writing secrets to disk, and including that secret as part of the build procedure.

Typically I prefer to only have secrets pulled outside of the build, and then perform the build with the resulting data so you don't need the secret inside the build itself. E.g. instead of pulling a private code repo from inside a container with the login credentials, do the pull from the repo outside of docker and then do the build with resulting code repo. This is also somewhere a multi-stage build could do some of the work with secret values injected and then copy the result to an image that doesn't have any of the secrets. The build host would have secrets in some of the layers of some stages, but not in any of the layers of the final stage that is pushed to a registry server.

Comment: Ah I hadn't considered that. I guess I would basically do the build as a 'publish' and then change the dockerfile to copy those artifacts into the app directory on the image. That way the the external build environment is responsible for keeping those secrets. AppVeyor has an encryption tool for that stuff, and locally, it would just be the normal global creds which are also encrypted. I'll try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Baking/embedding secrets in a docker image at built-time is not secure and results in a non-portable image. Instead, I suggest the following more secure ways:

1. Pull encrypted secrets from the orchestrator like:

   [Kubernetes secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/)

   [Docker Swarm secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/)
2. [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io)
3. Install Ansible in the container and pull secrets using [Ansible vault](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/vault.html)
4. Pull secrets from a trusted Certificate Authority

Comment: How would you perform a build that _uses_ a secret from the above list without baking that secret into the image?

Comment: @BMitch build-time secrets can be pulled by the Dockerfile when building the image using approaches like environment variables, `--build-arg`, SSH, vault, etc. Some info is in http://elasticcompute.io/2016/01/22/build-time-secrets-with-docker-containers/, https://medium.com/@mccode/dont-embed-configuration-or-secrets-in-docker-images-7b2e0f916fdd and https://runnable.com/docker/rails/managing-secrets-during-docker-builds.